# magento 2 i want to add some new Currency

Tags: magento2, currency

How to add new Currency in Magento 2 in backend I saw some currency is there more than that I want to add new MYR, SGD, LKR

Comment: What is the currency you want to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to below links

> admin -> store -> configuration -> currency setup(from left menu) -> Allowed Currencies (select your currencies here. to select multiple please press ctrl + click on your desired currencies)

AUD, GBP, CAD, EUR, MYR, SGD, LKR, USD

these are short form of currencies so please take care while selecting currencies

thanks i hope it will be helpful for you !!